# How to execute client functions remotely?

Tags: python, exec, rpc

I have a closed, secure network. I want to pass my code to executor and execute it in there. I want to be able to see it's console output (progress/info) while it will be doing it.

So say we had a function that takes no arguments in our current client code, how to execute it on server and get output back? Is there A Python framework for such use case?

Comment: You need to read David Beazley's [original generators tutorial](http://dabeaz.com/generators/) (select the presentation slides). Pay particular attention to Part 7. For the output, pay attention to Part 5 where he discusses "tailing a file".

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify enough details to give an elaborate answer. For instance, what the scale of your system is, how many 'executors' there shall be, if it should scale automatically et cetera.

However, for what you asked, [Pyro4](http://pyro4.readthedocs.io) should be able to do this for you. It allows you to call a member function on a remote machine as if it was local. It does require you to run a small server process on your executor nodes.

If you capture `sys.stdout` in the executor and yield the lines as generator results, you can easily stream the output to the calling application as well, because Pyro4 supports remote generators. You may want to buffer the output though, if you don't want unneccessary delays in your executor.

*edit:* the upcoming Pyro 4.62 release introduces support for the 'cloudpickle' serializer. Pyro4 has had support for the 'dill' serializer for a long time. Both of these allow you to actually send the function itself to the server.  This means that once you have a (very small) server running that accepts a callable object, you can then send *anything* you want to it to be remotely executed.